# How to instantly change name of variable for all references in project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, refactoring

I am working on some game in VS10, and I want to change the name of some variable, because I want to expand the game, however there is so much references to it, that I don't know from where to start. Is there any hotkey in VS10 that will do this in a moment for me? I know there is NetBeans hotkey CTRL+H, but this doesn't work for VS10.

Comment: I don't know if this works in the VC++ editor, but try renaming the variable and not moving the cursor. If a little blue box appears beneath the cursor, hover over it with the mouse and pick "Rename to ...". If there is no blue box, ignore me.

Comment: Possibly you can right click on that variable name and try to find "refactor" sort of thing.

Comment: Visual Assist X from http://www.wholetomato.com/ will allow you to do this sort of refactoring pretty easily.  I don't believe there is a way to do it without some sort of addon.

Answer (score 6):

First, any variable should always be declared and used in the smallest of scope.

In VS2010, whenever you rename a variable, it will prompt you whether you want all references to this variable is to be so renamed.  A little red bar will appear underneath the name where you changed it.  Move your mouse to that bar and an icon will appear with "Options to update references to the renamed object".  You can choose between renaming all right away or with preview.

(The ability to rename all references to the renamed variable disappears when you go and rename another different variable.  Perhaps there is a way to go back to an older rename but I have not found it.)

I tried renaming a public property of a class.  The automatic renaming works too for references to that public property, at least when both are within the same code file.

Answer (score 3):

As Retired Ninja said in his comment, you pretty much need add-ons for Visual Studio (like Visual Assist X).

Installing Visual Assist will give you a menu like this:

[image]

... where the "Find References" button searches for all references to that variable/function/namespace/etc and replaces it (not just a plain text search).

Other alternative is to open the "Find and Replace" window (press Ctrl+F), and click "Quick Replace". From there you can do a plain text search and replace (there's also wildcard and regex support (under "Find Options->Use:), if that helps).

Comment: In the stock Visual Studio, right clicking a variable name and you have the option of Find All References Ctrl+K,R , and it will list all references to that variable in the Find Symbol Results window.

Answer (score 0):

There is CTRL+H in VS10 too. If you press it on the right side pops out panel which is basically interface for what you want to do about the modification. It has everything included, to modify that name only in the document/s which is/are currently opened, or even in the whole project. Bad thing is that replaces that name with everything it encounters, except for header name. So if I have something like fruit.h and I want to rename it in apple.h, everything will be renamed to apple.h except the name file, so it will throw an exception that aformentioned header couldn't be found.

Comment: Moved this out of the question, where the asker had added it as an edit. If this is the asker's preferred solution, it should be added as an answer, then chosen as the answer.

Comment: I don't support this answer, as search-and-replace ≠ rename-a-variable. The latter is a better solution, but might not have been supported in the version of VS2010 you were using. I believe it's been a feature of Pro versions for about a decade--maybe more.